# Agrupar consultar para si existe la informacion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando con SQL Server versión 2007

Necesito poder generar una única consulta que me traiga 3 columnas y 1 fila, de la siguiente manera:

| licencia | acarreo | libreta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | false | true |

La consulta para la libreta es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT 
TOP 1
    sol.id as id
FROM wapUsuarios wu
    LEFT JOIN wapPersonas per ON per.ReferenciaID = wu.PersonaID
    LEFT JOIN libretas_usuarios usu ON usu.id_wappersonas = per.ReferenciaID
    LEFT JOIN libretas_solicitudes sol ON sol.id_usuario_solicitante = usu.id
WHERE wu.ReferenciaID = 20936 ORDER BY id DESC
```

La consulta para licencia es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT Vigente as vig FROM dbo.licLicencias WHERE Licencia = 3196020
```

La consulta para acarreo es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    a.PATENTE as patente
FROM dbo.wapUsuarios wu
    LEFT JOIN AC_ACARREO a ON a.ID_PERSONA = wu.PersonaID
    LEFT JOIN AC_MOTIVO m ON m.ID_MOTIVO = a.ID_MOTIVO
    LEFT JOIN AC_PLAYA p ON p.ID_PLAYA= a.ID_PLAYA
WHERE wu.ReferenciaID = 20936 and a.BORRADO_LOGICO = 'NO'
```

Para cada una de las consultas si trae el valor como `null` en la tabla final debería indicar un `false` caso contrario un `true`

**Por ejemplo**

Si en al consulta de libreta el id es null
Si en la consulta de licencia el vig **no** es null
Si en la consulta de acarreo la patente **no** es null

| licencia | acarreo | libreta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | true | true |

Espero poder haberme expresado bien

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: SQLServer 7? Eso corría en Windows95. Seguro???

Comment: Perdon SQL Server 2007

Answer (score 0):

La solución es usar un CASE. ALgo como

```
SELECT 
a, b, c,
..., 
CASE
    WHEN licencia IS NULL THEN false
    ELSE true
    AS [licencia_bool],
...
```